# opencv houghCircles ( .... ?PARAM1?, ?PARAM2?)

Tags: c++, c, opencv

```
cvHoughCircles(Mat& image, vector<Vec3f>& circles, int method, double dp, double minDist, double param1=100, double param2=100, int minRadius=0, int maxRadius=0)
```

according to documentation:

> **param1** - The first method-specific parameter.
>   in the case of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT it is
>   the higher threshold of the two passed
>   to Canny() edge detector (the lower
>   one will be twice smaller)

I really don't understand point of `param1` and `param2`. I've tried plenty different values, but still no idea. 
Could anyone please explain them to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the only implemented method in `cvHoughCircles()` is `CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT`.

So,

`param1` - refers to the edge threshold that will be used by the Canny edge detector (applied to a grayscale image). `cvCanny()` accepts two thresholds and is internally invoked by `cvHoughCircles()`. Therefore the higher (first) threshold is set to `param1` (passed as argument into `cvHoughCircles()`) and the lower (second) threshold is set to half of this value.

`param2`- Is the value for accumulator threshold. This value is used in the accumulator plane that must be reached so that a line is retrieved.

I would recommend you to read this [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130), which is in my opinion the best one describing OpenCv.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's not so complicated. I should pay more attention while reading doc :-) 
Unfortunatelly deadlines are approaching and I cannot afford reading long manuals.

Comment: @myro You're welcome! That book is really good. It's worth a reading.